# Accessing 'constant' variables not working

Tags: solidity, web3js

I need to access some constant variables in a smart contract, but I'm not being able to. 
Here's my code:

```
decimals = await contractInstance.methods.decimals().call();
```

'decimals' is a constant in a ERC20 contract deployed in Ropsten.
I thought the compiler generated getters for those automatically, but I'm getting this error:

```
TypeError: contractInstance.methods.decimals is not a function
```

Is there another way to fetch a constant except from it's default getter?
Note: The contract is already published and it don't have an explicit method to get the 'decimals' constant.

Comment: Let's have a look at the code where decimals is declared.

Comment: I decided to just hardcode the constant in my code, but still this is a bug.
This is the line of code:
```uint8 public constant decimals = 18;```

Answer (score 2):

`constant public` gives a free getter.

You can play with this in Remix to see it.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.1;

contract Getter { 

    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;

}
```

Here it is in Remix so you can see the getter working:

[image]

There may be a bug in your contract and that should be a concern. Another possibility is the way you instantiate the contract in JavaScript. I don't think it's possible to pinpoint the issue more precisely with the information we've got here.

Hope it helps.